# webpack < 5 used to include polyfills Issue after installing firbase-admin in angular

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-admin

I'm trying to push notification to my app through my client side appliction using [this guide](https://morioh.com/p/8e139d937058).
But after running
`npm install firebase-admin --save`
and building the app I got a lot of this error:

```
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
```

Another example of the error:

```
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
        - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "os": false }
```

And these are just two of many, I have more.
I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68997033/webpack-5-issue-when-using-firebase-admin) which have the same problem, but the answer is for react while I'm using angualr.

I also can't find any webpack to add these fallbacks or something like that.

Thanks!